# Crossword Puzzle Implementation as a CSP

Tags: c#, puzzle, crossword

my program which is written in c#,gets a grid of black cells and blank cells and a list of words as input and it should fit the words into the grid.
I wanna generate this crossword puzzle by CSP algorithms and I wanna get words(sets of across or down blanks)as variables,but I don't know how to determine which cells together are a variable. for example if I have this matrix as input which 0 means blank cell and 1 means black cell:

```
    0001
    0100
    0000
    1010
```

how can my program understand that how many variables there are and what are their lengths?
I tried many times to write it with nested "for"s but I couldn't.
I will appreaciate any points.

Comment: A crossword as a Cryptographic Service Provider?  Puzzling question.

Comment: No,its just a crossword puzzle but in fact generating it not solving it.
we give the program a list of words and it should make a crossword puzzle using them.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still reading this, do you have any CSP algorithms (or frameworks) in mind or trying to build one also?

If you do use some CSP framework, they should have an interface to add the constraints
for this problem

If you want to create a CSP framework for this problem there are some links (on SO also) which deal with CSP and/or crossword compilation

eg http://thesis.cambon.dk/ as used by CWC open soure compiler